# ElasticSearch NEST Aggregations

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I did a lot of googeling and checked the documentation for NEST and ElasticSearch but I was not able to find a working example / solve my  problem.

I made an example. In this example I want to query the number of distinct Last_Names and the SUM of the Salaries per family.

```
    class Employee
    {
        public string First_Name { get; set; }
        public string Last_Name { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }

        public Employee(string first_name, string last_name, int salary)
        {
            this.First_Name = first_name;
            this.Last_Name = last_name;
            this.Salary = salary;
        }
        public Employee() { }
    }
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create 4 employees
        Employee al = new Employee("Al", "Bundy", 1500);
        Employee bud = new Employee("Bud", "Bundy", 975);
        Employee marcy = new Employee("Marcy", "Darcy", 4500);
        Employee jefferson = new Employee("Jefferson", "Darcy", 0);

        // add the 4 employees to the index
        client.Index<Employee>(al);
        client.Index<Employee>(bud);
        client.Index<Employee>(marcy);
        client.Index<Employee>(jefferson);

        // query the index
        var result = client.Search<Employee>(s => s
            .Aggregations(a => a
                .Terms("Families", ts => ts
                    .Field(o => o.Last_Name)
                    .Size(10)
                    .Aggregations(aa => aa
                        .Sum("FamilySalary", sa => sa
                            .Field(o => o.Salary)
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );

        // Get the number of different families (Result should be 2: Bundy and Darcy)  
        // and get the family-salary of family Bundy and the family-salary for the Darcys
        var names = result.Aggs.Terms("Families");
        // ?? var x = names.Sum("Bundy");           
    }
```

I need the following informations from elastic: 
* there are two different families in the index 
  * family Bundy earns 2475 
  * family Darcy earns 4500

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a complete example

```cs
private static void Main()
{
    var defaultIndex = "employees";

    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"))
        .InferMappingFor<Employee>(i => i
            .IndexName(defaultIndex)
        )
        .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex)
        // following settings are useful while developing
        // but probably don't want to use them in production
        .DisableDirectStreaming()
        .PrettyJson()
        .OnRequestCompleted(callDetails =>
        {
            if (callDetails.RequestBodyInBytes != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"{callDetails.HttpMethod} {callDetails.Uri} \n" +
                    $"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(callDetails.RequestBodyInBytes)}");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{callDetails.HttpMethod} {callDetails.Uri}");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();

            if (callDetails.ResponseBodyInBytes != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Status: {callDetails.HttpStatusCode}\n" +
                         $"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(callDetails.ResponseBodyInBytes)}\n" +
                         $"{new string('-', 30)}\n");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Status: {callDetails.HttpStatusCode}\n" +
                         $"{new string('-', 30)}\n");
            }
        });

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    if (client.IndexExists(defaultIndex).Exists)
        client.DeleteIndex(defaultIndex);

    client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, c => c
        .Settings(s => s
            .NumberOfShards(1)
        )
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<Employee>(mm => mm
                .AutoMap()
            )
        )
    );

    // Create 4 employees
    var al = new Employee("Al", "Bundy", 1500);
    var bud = new Employee("Bud", "Bundy", 975);
    var marcy = new Employee("Marcy", "Darcy", 4500);
    var jefferson = new Employee("Jefferson", "Darcy", 0);

    client.IndexMany(new [] { al, bud, marcy, jefferson });

    // refresh the index after indexing. We do this here for example purposes,
    // but in a production system, it's preferable to use the refresh interval
    // see https://www.elastic.co/blog/refreshing_news
    client.Refresh(defaultIndex);

    // query the index
    var result = client.Search<Employee>(s => s
        .Aggregations(a => a
            .Terms("Families", ts => ts
                .Field(o => o.Last_Name.Suffix("keyword")) // use the keyword sub-field for terms aggregation
                .Size(10)
                .Aggregations(aa => aa
                    .Sum("FamilySalary", sa => sa
                        .Field(o => o.Salary)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    // Get the number of different families (Result should be 2: Bundy and Darcy)  
    // and get the family-salary of family Bundy and the family-salary for the Darcys
    var names = result.Aggs.Terms("Families");

    foreach(var name in names.Buckets)
    {
        var sum = name.Sum("FamilySalary");
        Console.WriteLine($"* family {name.Key} earns {sum.Value}");
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }

    public Employee(string first_name, string last_name, int salary)
    {
        this.First_Name = first_name;
        this.Last_Name = last_name;
        this.Salary = salary;
    }
    public Employee() { }
}
```

This outputs

> - family Bundy earns 2475
> - family Darcy earns 4500

A few points:

1. I've explicitly created the index with a mapping for employee using [automapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/auto-map.html). Whilst the example will work without the index or explicit mapping, I added it for clarity so that you can see what is created in the console output. You can change how employee is mapped to suite your needs.
2. Bulk index all documents in one request
3. Refresh the index after bulk indexing. In a production system, you generally do not call `refresh` after indexing operations because it causes a Lucene segment to be written in the underlying inverted index. Whilst there is a background process to merge segments, [having *many* small segments can be a problem.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/merge-process.html) It's best to let the refresh interval do its thing. Refresh is called here only to make the documents available to search following indexing.
4. The terms aggregation should run on the [`keyword` sub field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/multi-fields.html) that is created with automapping, when mapping a `string` property. A keyword field datatype indexes the value *verbatim* and leverages doc values, a columnar data structure that works well for aggregations and sorting.
5. The terms aggregation contains a collection of buckets, where each bucket key will be the term. Each bucket may have sub aggregations; in this case a sum aggregation.